# Get The Maximum Number of records from a specific ID in mysql

Tags: mysql

What I want is,
To get the TOP Customers according to their Orders they have made from the Database.
It is not based on SUM of any column in database.
It should be according to number of records.
Suppose a `CustomerID` has placed 15 `orders`. And another `CustomerID` has 10 Orders
The 15 Orders ID should above and 10 Should below.
I am trying with mysqli but It is not possible for me to do it. What I am doing is just to get `mysqli_num_rows()` and My MySqli query is

```
SELECT * FROM  Reservations GROUP BY CustomerID
```

How I can get the result having Maximum Records top and Minimum Records lower.

[Image is Here](https://prnt.sc/vl7xr8)

Please see the Above image to understand what I am searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, count(CustomerID) c from Reservation
group by CustomerID
order by c desc;
```

first, make a group by and make the order as you want ASC or DESC

Comment: Never use `SELECT *` !